# why is cornerRadius giving me a diamond shape?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, mask, cornerradius

I'm trying to make a circular profile picture and I'm following the steps set at the end of this tutorial (http://valeriodonfrancesco.com/add-circular-mask-uiimage-easy-way/) but I keep coming out with a diamond-like shape. What am I doing wrong? here's my code

```
  @IBOutlet weak var profilePic: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width/2
    profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: try setting profilePic.cliptobounds = true

Comment: do this in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1):

Please add **clipsToBounds**

```
profilePic.layer.cornerRadius  = profilePic.frame.size.width/2
profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
profilePic.clipsToBounds       = true // Add this line in your code
```

Comment: did you find clipToBounds in docs ? is not it clipsToBounds ?

Answer (score 0):

> profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = profilePic.frame.size.width/2

Is your frame a square? If the width > height, you may get funny shapes.

Comment: There's a aspect ratio of 1:1 on the image and it still produces the diamond. Both height and width are 128